# How to convert NVD3 bar graphs into area line graphs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, nvd3.js

My [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ymrqIOGTBqF6TVMTvC4T?p=preview).

[image: linePlusBarChart]

Currently my NVD3 chart is based on their [linePlusBarChart](https://github.com/nvd3-community/nvd3/blob/046c136f75e3b6e4c8b44ebc1f8e75586c3825f6/examples/linePlusBarChart.html).

The problem is that in my real app I actually have much more bar tick data (4000+) so the bars get super thin and are hard to see, thus I need to instead use a Line Area graph instead. (This isn't apparent in my plnkr example because it's using a small fake sample size for the bar graph.)

Has anyone else tried to accomplish this? Turning the Bars into a Line Area graph?

Code:

```js
var data = [{
  "key": "Price",
  "color": "#4C73FF",
  "values": [
    [1443621600000, 71.89],
    [1443619800000, 75.51],
    [1443618000000, 68.49],
    [1443616200000, 62.72],
    [1443612600000, 70.39],
    [1443610800000, 59.77]
  ]
}, {
  "key": "Quantity",
  "bar": true,
  "values": [
    [1136005200000, 1],
    [1138683600000, 2],
    [1141102800000, 1],
    [1143781200000, 0],
    [1146369600000, 1],
    [1149048000000, 0]
  ]
}];

nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
    .margin({
      top: 20,
      right: 40,
      bottom: 50,
      left: 40
    })
    .x(function(d, i) {
      return i
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d[1]
    })
    .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

  chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    var dx = data[0].values[d] && data[0].values[d][0] || 0;
    // return time in hours:
    return d3.time.format('%I:%M')(new Date(dx));
  });

  chart.y1Axis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

  chart.y2Axis
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
      return '$' + d3.format(',f')(d)
    });

  chart.bars.forceY([0]);
  chart.lines.interactive(false);
  chart.height(300);

  d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(data)
    .transition().duration(500)
    .call(chart);

  chart.update();
  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
```

Comment: There's [multiChart](https://github.com/nvd3-community/nvd3/blob/e618c7b3845bbfc07912eb71d7b2e525d4c0b4a5/examples/multiChart.html) which combines lines, bars and areas.

Comment: Thanks, looking into that now... want to post your answer?

Comment: I'm at work lol... I can post the multi-chart example as an answer. Any further customizations required?

Comment: If you have the time to post a plunkr with the multichart example that would be a great bonus to the answer for other users :) I'm trying to get it working now in my app. Running into a few errors, but should have them ironed out by tomorrow. Basically need to make sure that data 1 shows up on the right Y axis and data 2 shows up on the left Y axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, NVD3 gives you [multiChart](https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#multiChart) ([example](https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/multiChart.html)), which combines line/bar/area charts. Note:

- *yAxis1* is on the left, *yAxis2* is on the right.
- Component charts with the suffix "1" use the left y-axis: *lines1*, *bars1*, *stack1*.
- You can't use *forceY* because [it's not supported by the stacked area chart](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/602) as of 1.8.1. You need to manually calculate the y-domains of your data and set them on the chart using *yDomain1* and *yDomain2*.

Finally, here's a simple multi-chart (NVD3 1.8.1) using your example data, with quantity (area) on the left and price (line) on the right:

```js
var data = [{
  "key": "Price",
  "type": "line",
  "yAxis": 2,
  "values": [
    [1443621600000, 71.89],
    [1443619800000, 75.51],
    [1443618000000, 68.49],
    [1443616200000, 62.72],
    [1443612600000, 70.39],
    [1443610800000, 59.77],
  ]
}, {
  "key": "Quantity",
  "type": "area",
  "yAxis": 1,
  "values": [
    [1136005200000, 1],
    [1138683600000, 2],
    [1141102800000, 1],
    [1143781200000, 0],
    [1146369600000, 1],
    [1149048000000, 0],
  ]
}];

data = data.map(function(series) {
  series.values = series.values.map(function(d) {
    return {
      x: d[0],
      y: d[1]
    }
  });
  return series;
});

nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.multiChart()
    .margin({
      top: 20,
      right: 40,
      bottom: 50,
      left: 40
    })
    .yDomain1([0, 10])
    .yDomain2([0, 100]) // hard-coded :<
    .interpolate("linear") // don't smooth out the lines
    .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

  chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.time.format('%I:%M')(new Date(d));
  });
  chart.yAxis1.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
  chart.yAxis2.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return '$' + d3.format(',f')(d)
  });

  chart.lines2.interactive(false); // line chart, right axis

  d3.select('svg#chart')
    .datum(data)
    .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

  chart.update();
  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
  return chart;
});
```

```css
text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}
svg {
  display: block;
}
html,
body,
svg#chart {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="chart"></svg>
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks for the explanation and additional info about the config.

Comment: I created a plnkr here based on your code as well: http://plnkr.co/edit/2pFDDITuPc7XaL0eR4AA?p=preview Do you know what the purpose of the `map` function is? I see somehow for the `y1` axis values Array those objects have an added `display` object as well as a `series` and `seriesIndex` now as well.

Comment: The map function converts each value (e.g. [1136005200000, 1]) into an object with x and y fields, so you don't need to call `chart.x()` and `chart.y()` later on. The other fields you mentioned are added for D3's use.